# In React use the Promise Object Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs, promise, components

in my api.js

```
export function getTeamById(teamId) {
  return fetch(`api값`).then(
    (response) => response.json().then((result) => result.data)
  );
}
```

```
getTeamById(42).then((i) => console.log(i.name));
```

I use temporary 42 then result
[image]

But, in my components

```
<div>{getTeamById(42).then((i) => i.name)}</div>
```

it comes an Error like this

react-dom.development.js:13231 Uncaught Error:

Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]).

If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

How can i express data in componets

please help me

I want to express team-name in my screen

like this

Leicester City

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call functions inside return statements as you have done here:

```
<div>{getTeamById(42).then((i) => i.name)}</div>
```

You need to call it before return statement, store the result in variable, and then display in the return statement. So, the correct code will be:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const showName = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState(null)
    getTeamById(42).then((i) => setName(i.name));
  return (
    <div>{name}</div>
  )
}

export default showName;
```

Note that your component name can be anything. For simplifying things, I have kept it as `showName`.